# How to preserve custom headers case in ruby

Tags: ruby, http, http-headers, case-sensitive, custom-headers

On a note HTTP spec says that headers are case insensitive, we have a need to call a service which is having the case sensitive headers.

Below is my code

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

url = URI("Service URL")

http = Net::HTTP::Proxy('127.0.0.1', '8888').new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["content-type"] = 'text/xml'
request["charset"] = 'utf-8'
request["accept"] = 'text/xml'
request["host"] = 'abc.com'
request["HMACSignature"] = 'dsfsdfsdf'

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

the custom header is being receiving as Hmacversion.

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710373/preserving-case-in-http-headers-with-rubys-nethttp) but it is not working.

Is there any work around for this

Comment: "custom header is being receiving as Hmacversion." You mean Hmacsignature I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at all possible, I would try to change the server, which is violating HTTP standards by treating request header keys as case-sensitive - ["Field names are case-insensitive"](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html). That error will mess with browsers, caches and so on.

If you can't fix it, I would probably try [another HTTP client library](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) that preserves case, not Net::HTTP. Just make sure that library doesn't use Net::HTTP behind the scenes. You could try Excon for example (I'm not sure if it preserves case but it has a lot of low-level control).

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to force case sensitive headers.

```
class CaseSensitivePost < Net::HTTP::Post
  def initialize_http_header(headers)
    @header = {}
    headers.each{|k,v| @header[k.to_s] = [v] }
  end

  def [](name)
    @header[name.to_s]
  end

  def []=(name, val)
    if val
      @header[name.to_s] = [val]
    else
      @header.delete(name.to_s)
    end
  end

  def capitalize(name)
    name
  end
end
```

Usage example:

```
post = CaseSensitivePost.new(url, {myCasedHeader: '1'})
post.body = body
http = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
http.request(post)
```

Others suggested creating custom string class, that won't get downcased or capitalized.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121370/979995